# survival analysis and small numbers in certain groups

Tags: survival

I am conducting a survival analysis of time to loss for employees in a company. I have a couple of questions:

1. I have a dataset of employees who started at different times over a 10 year period. Is it OK to conduct an analysis of all employees combined over this period, and maybe include a variable in the model for year of start date? I would just break the analysis down by year of start date (e.g. 2010 hires, 2011 hires), however, the numbers of employees starts to get small, for example, in one year only 10 people were hired.
2. When showing Kaplan Meier survival curves by different groups, is there any kind of general guideline I can use for how many people are needed in each category? I have some small groups like 10, and am wondering whether it is too unreliable to even show curves for these groups. Or, is it better to still show the curves and provide a caveat about small numbers?

I would be very grateful for any feedback.

Thank you,
Caroline